# Get linear and quadratic terms from sympy expression

Tags: python, arrays, sympy

I have an generic expression `E`  which are dependent of `X(t)`(an array of variables) and `dX(t)`.
Is there a easy way to get `linear` and `quadratic`  terms from `E`?
My actual code works only when `E` is simple.

My goal is to get matrix `M`, `V`, `K`, `A`, `B` and `C`  such that `E = dX @ M @ dX + dX @ V @ X + X @ K @ X + A @ dX + B @ X + C`

For exemple

```py
import sympy as sp

t = sp.symbols("t")
x = sp.Function("x")(t)
y = sp.Function("y")(t)
dx = sp.diff(x, t)
dy = sp.diff(y, t)
X = sp.Array([x, y])
dX = sp.Array([dx, dy])

E = 7*(dx**2) + 2*dx*dy + 6*(dy**2)  # M = [[7, 1],
                                     #      [1, 6]]
E += 4*dx*x + 6*dx*y + 3*dy*x + 5*dy*y  # V = [[4, 6],
                                        #      [3, 5]]
E += (-3)*x**2 + (-4)*x*y + (-5)*y**2  # K = [[-3, -2],
                                       #      [-2, -5]]
E += 1*dx + (-7)*dy  # A = [1, -7]
E += (-5)*x + 9*y  # B = [-5, 9]
E += 80  # C = 80
```

Until now, what I do is take the derivative and subtract the terms manually.
The following code works fine when I have constant values:

```py
diff = sp.derive_by_array
def dot(A, B):
    # Matrix multiplication of A and B
    ndimA = len(sp.shape(A))
    C = sp.tensorproduct(A, B)
    D = sp.tensorcontraction(C, (ndimA-1, ndimA))
    return D

M = diff( diff(E, dX), dX)/2
E -= dot(dX, dot(M, dX))
V = diff( diff(E, X), dX)
E -= dot(dX, dot(V, X))
K = diff( diff(E, X), X)/2
E -= dot(X, dot(K, X))
A = diff(E, dX)
E -= dot(A, dX)
B = diff(E, X)
E -= dot(B, X)
C = sp.expand(E)
```

But the results are wrong when I put nonconstant terms. For exemple with `E = cos(x)`:

```py
# expected
M = [[0, 0],
     [0, 0]]
V = [[0, 0],
     [0, 0]]
K = [[0, 0],
     [0, 0]]
A = [0, 0]
B = [0, 0]
C = cos(x)

# gotten
M = [[0, 0],
     [0, 0]]
V = [[0, 0],
     [0, 0]]
K = [[-cos(x)/2, 0],
     [0, 0]]
A = [0, 0]
B = [-x(t)**2*sin(x(t))/2 + x(t)*cos(x(t)) - sin(x(t)), 0]
C = x(t)**3*sin(x(t))/2 - x(t)**2*cos(x(t))/2 + x(t)*sin(x(t)) + cos(x(t))
```

I looked towards a solution using the [Advanced Expression Manipulation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html) and the function `srepr` to decompose `E`, but I thought it should exist an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using symbolic matrix and using `sympy.solve` to find the solution. I create `symbolic function arrays`, then I compute the scalar `Esup` as a desired expression and I solve to find the value inside each matrix.

```py
import numpy as np

all_variables = []
def MatrixFunction(name, shape):
    ndim = len(shape)
    M = np.zeros(shape, dtype="object")
    if ndim == 1:
        for i in range(shape[0]):
            M[i] = sp.Function(f"{name}{i}")(x, y)
            all_variables.append(M[i])
    elif ndim == 2:
        for i in range(shape[0]):
            for j in range(shape[1]):
                M[i, j] = sp.Function(f"{name}{i}{j}")(x, y)
                all_variables.append(M[i, j])
    return sp.MutableDenseNDimArray(M)

M = MatrixFunction("M", [len(X), len(X)])
V = MatrixFunction("V", [len(X), len(X)])
K = MatrixFunction("K", [len(X), len(X)])
A = MatrixFunction("A", [len(X)])
B = MatrixFunction("B", [len(X)])
C = sp.Function("C")(x, y)
all_variables.append(C)
equations = []
for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(X)):
        equations.append(M[i, j] - M[j, i])
        equations.append(K[i, j] - K[j, i])

Esup = dot(dX, dot(M, dX))
Esup += dot(dX, dot(V, X))
Esup += dot(X, dot(K, X))
Esup += dot(A, dX)
Esup += dot(B, X)
Esup += C

dife = E - Esup
poly = sp.Poly(dife, (x, y, dx, dy))
equations += poly.coeffs()

solution = sp.solve(equations, all_variables)
for var, val in solution.items():
    C = C.subs(var, val)
    for i in range(len(X)):
        A[(i,)] = A[(i,)].subs(var, val)
        B[(i,)] = B[(i,)].subs(var, val)
        for j in range(len(X)):
            M[i, j] = M[i, j].subs(var, val)
            V[i, j] = V[i, j].subs(var, val)
            K[i, j] = K[i, j].subs(var, val)
```